# How to avoid dropping a dimension in linear model residuals?

Tags: r, lm

In R, `lm(...)$residuals` if passed a matrix response returns a matrix with same column names as the response, *unless* the matrix has only one column, in which case it drops down to a vector and hence no column name is present.  For example:

```
nc <- 1
Y <- matrix(rnorm(4*nc), ncol = nc, dimnames = list(NULL, letters[1:nc]))
colnames(lm(Y~1)$residual) # returns NULL
nc <- 2
Y <- matrix(rnorm(4*nc), ncol = nc, dimnames = list(NULL, letters[1:nc]))
colnames(lm(Y~1)$residual) # returns c("a", "b")
```

Is there some way to avoid this (akin to `drop=F`) so the residuals preserve the column names?  (Obviously one approach is to add them back in again manually.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no.

`lm()` calls `lm.fit()` for model fitting, which further calls C routine `dqrls` *(modified LINPACK QR factorization with partial column pivoting)*. The following line is the heart of `lm.fit() / lm()`:

```
z <- .Call(C_Cdqrls, x, y, tol, FALSE)
```

Residuals are returned in `z$residuals`. Now,

- if your response is a matrix of more than one columns, this is a matrix;
- whereas if your response is a vector, or even a matrix of single column, this is a vector.

Later, `z` is expanded with for example, fitted values, to finally form a complete `lm` object.

The behaviour of the internal C code can not be changed, so there is no option for you to control `lm` to get what you want. So yes, if you really want a one-column matrix for residuals, do it yourself.